# On the stackexchange.com filters page, use a background color instead of having to load an external image

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, images, stackexchange.com

On the [filters page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags) on StackExchange.com, a static external image is loaded to force a background colour instead of applying a CSS `background-color` for the HTML element `.filters-sidebar .filters ul li.current`. Here's the image:

[image: arrow image used as highlight]

My recommendation is to apply a CSS `background-color` to the element instead of loading a static background image from a server.  To generate the desired shape, you can also use CSS.

In plain English, the area affected is the name of the selected filter in the "Select Filter" box near the top of the page, e.g. "Favorite Tags":

[image: Tag filter selection box showing the "arrow" image displayed]

Comment: The site was designed more than a decade ago, when IE8 was the most common browser people used.

Comment: It's set with the `background` CSS property. I don't see a problem with it; it's a little outmoded, but not _wrong_ (and CSS hacks, like we see on the new voting arrows, are even less elegant).

Comment: *Why* is this a feature request? What problem does it solve? FRs typically should provide justification.

Comment: @VLAZ Because using static images as hardcoded background colours are not compliant with many accessibility technologies.  Such use also makes implementing one's own themes (such as dark themes) unnecessarily cumbersome.